# Java PhantomJS NETWORK_ERR XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to get the page https://secure.twitch.tv/login with PhantomJS in Java using Selenium, but on the driver.get(...) I always get crashed with this error. I've tried implementing this:

```
String [] phantomJsArgs = {"--web-security=no", "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes"};
desireCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_GHOSTDRIVER_CLI_ARGS, phantomJsArgs);
```

But that doesn't seem to make a difference. Does anyone know a workaround?

Here is some code:

```
private void setup(){
        DesiredCapabilities desireCaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        desireCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "C:\\Users\\Scott\\workspace\\Twitch Bot v2\\libs\\phantomjs.exe");
        desireCaps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
        String [] phantomJsArgs = {"--disable-web-security"};
        desireCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_GHOSTDRIVER_CLI_ARGS, phantomJsArgs);
        driver = new PhantomJSDriver(desireCaps); 
        //driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    }
```

This is what the console is printing out when I try to grab the twitch page.

[image: This is what the console prints out when I try to get the twitch link.]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to load the page with async XMLHttpRequest, but the server does not provide cross origin headers (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) in its response. Loading such resource with async XMLHttpRequest is discouraged for security reasons.

To bypass this limitation, add the flag `--disable-web-security` to phantomJsArgs.

Comment: Do I add that to the list of strings phantomJsArgs? And do I have to do "--disable-web-security=true"?

Comment: Yes, add this to the list of strings phantomJsArgs. No, you don't need to specify `=true`, just `--disable-web-security`.

Comment: Still getting the same error. NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101: A network error occurred in synchronous requests.

Comment: [INFO  - 2015-05-27T21:01:00.350Z] Session [7a5fe470-04b3-11e5-b241-fdd8345b66c9] - page.settings - {"XSSAuditingEnabled":false,"javascriptCanCloseWindows":true,"javascriptCanOpenWindows":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"loadImages":true,"localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled":false,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.0.0 Safari/538.1","webSecurityEnabled":true} Is it supposed to have webSecurityEnabled equal to true when it prints all this stuff to the console?

Comment: No, it seems that the capabilities that you set do not apply. Could you post more code, how exactly do you set the capabilities for the driver?

Comment: I sent an edit to you by accident. Please ignore that and look at my edited post for the code I used to setup the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Just another guess what might be going on: phantomjs still defaults to SSL 3.0 requests but lots of websites have disabled SSL 3.0 so these requests will fail. To use more modern protocols use the following option with phantomjs:

```
 --ssl-protocol=any
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, but I'm still getting the error. Do you know why my code isn't setting the web security properly?

Comment: I added in the error message into the post. Hopefully that helps :)